# Ruby on Rails, undefined method merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At the beginning let me excuse for easy question for those who are experienced but for me it is difficult right now. In the Rails in one of the views/_form.html.erb, I want to change line below (it works):

```
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :email %>
```

into hidden field that will hold the id of the user that is logged in. I try to change it into:

```
    <% f.hidden_field :user_id, :id %>
```

but it throws an error:

```
    NoMethodError in Orders#new
    undefined method `merge' for :id:Symbol
```

Can sb help me to solve that?

Comment: big recommendation: **Never trust users' input**. Do a double-check in the controller to make sure the user's id given is matching the current user that is connected (or eventually directly set the user's id in the Controller instead of using a hidden field in a view)

Comment: Good point. I do not need to send it in the form. So following your suggestion and code from Rakibul's comment: @current_user = User.find(params[:user_id]), I should update the Controller.

Comment: So now I have the scenario that I have logged user, and he/she adds a new order. I need to assign this order a proper user_id. How to do that not sending it in a form?

Comment: You should not trust the parameters, `params[:user_id]` can be modified manually. You probably have a session between your app and the end-user, in this session is stored the User's id (usually, depending on your user-sessions solution). Use this to set the `user_id` of the object beeing created/updated. Something like `Item.create(params[:item].merge(user_id: current_user.id))`

Comment: You can actually do: `@current_user = User.find(session["user_id]")`

Comment: Thank you guys. I need to work a little bit with your suggestions but they are pointing me in a good direction :)

Comment: See this article on how session works in Rails: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/
Should help you understand how session works in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (if you already have `current_user` method available):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

If you don't have `current_user` method implemented, in your corresponding controller, you can have something like this:

```
@current_user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Then, in your view, you can do:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
```

#### Update

After the above conversation, if you want to use session to store the user_id, then you can do something like this.

You can create a `SessionsHelper` module (which you can include in your `ApplicationController`) where you can define a `log_in` method:

```
  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

(You can also put this: `session[:user_id] = user.id` in the `create` action where you create an user.)

You can also define a `current_user` method in this module:

```
  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

Here are some other useful helper methods that you can add in this module:

```
  # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

**Finally, I would suggest you to take a look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem which is a very popular authentication solution for Rails application.**

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Devise. I checked it and thanks to current_user method I have access to user_id whenever I need it :)

Comment: Yeah. Devise is useful and has many helper methods that you would need. So why reinventing the wheel? :)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that it expects a hash, but you are putting an empty symbol.

You need to send a hash

If you have  the current_user method:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

If you don't, you may use this in your controller

```
   id = User.find(someid)
```

And keep the same code in the view.

[Look @ the documentation for more info](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field)

Answer (score 1):

The first two answers are correct. Here's why

`f.hidden_field` is a method on the form object you created somewhere either in that partial or in a file/partial that includes it. The documentation linked by Hristo Georgiev is for the `hidden_field` method from `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` ([link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L109)). The one you're trying to call is from `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` ([link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1291))

`hidden_field` works just as you seem to be expecting it to, ie

```
hidden_field(:user_object, :id)
```

**these are two different methods**

`f.hidden_field` works a bit differently, because it already has access to some of the information used to build the hidden field. It expects a method to call on the form object and an optional hash which it converts to attributes on the hidden field (thus the `:value => user.id` hash)

Assuming you had the following form

```
form_for(@user) do |f|
  ...
end
```

And you wanted the id to be a hidden field, you would put this within that block

```
f.hidden_field(:id)
```

That would generate the following HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user[id]" value="1" />
```

See [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1761) from ActionView

**TL;DR**

You're calling the `FormBuilder#hidden_field` method with the arguments expected by `FormHelper#hidden_field`